# Best way to do coupled numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

What is the best way to evaluate coupled integrations using NIntegrate? For eaxmple for the following function,

```
func = f[x2]*g[x1]
```

with (for demonstration),

```
f[x2]=x2 and g[x1]=x1
```

which I want to integrate from x1->{x2,1} and x2->{0,1}. Note that the x1 integration starts from x2.

```
test1=Integrate[f[x2]*Integrate[g[x1],{x1,x2,1}],{x2,0,1}] (*Analytic*)
test2=NIntegrate[f[x2]*NIntegrate[g[x1],{x1,x2,1}],{x2,0,1}] (*Numerical*)
```

test2 in fact gives correct result (0.125 in this case), however it also comes with the following error:

```
NIntegrate::nlim: x1 = x2 is not a valid limit of integration.
```

Can anyone suggest to do this kind of numerical integration in efficient way?

Comment: `Integrate[x1 x2, {x2, 0, 1}, {x1, x2, 1}]`?

Comment: NIntegrate[x1 x2, {x2, 0, 1}, {x1, x2, 1}] gives correct result without error.
But what is the problem if I do 
NIntegrate[x1 x2,  {x1, x2, 1},{x2, 0, 1}] ?

Comment: The earlier integration ranges precede the definitions of the later integration ranges, and thus cannot depend on them.

Comment: Sorry, but x1 integration is done first no? I wonder why
NIntegrate[f[x2]*NIntegrate[g[x1],{x1,x2,1}],{x2,0,1}]  shows error where the ordering is as it should be.

Comment: No, in `Integrate` the integration is done in the order that the integration ranges are specified. Without nested integrals, so long as the space of integration is the same the integral itself is the same. With nested integrals, it's a question of if the phase space is actually the same, but considering that they're separable (`x1` and `x2` are independent), they are, so it is. In the integration command you mention though, `x2` is done first since it's on the outside.

Comment: Thanks. But in nested integration, if I do the x2 integration first that leaves x1 integration range from x2 to 1. Which does not make sense. 
By hand I would do the x1 integral first which gives 1/2(1-x2^2)  then x2 integration works on x2/2(1-x2^2) from 0 to 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77254/discussion-between-eyorble-and-goutam-das).

Comment: in the `test2` case the error arises as the "inner" `NIntegrate` is first evaluated symbolically and fails as `x2` is symbolic.  The "outer" `NIntegrate` then proceeds to evaluate it with numeric values for `x2` so you get the correct result.